# Issue with translator alert

Tags: javascript, arrays, alerts

I have created a new iteration of the translator I have been working on with the help of the commenters of my previous post, however now I am having the issue where even if a user types a correct number, and selects the language "French" with a caps, you get both the translation AND the error message in the else statement. This doesnt happen with the German translations, that works fine, it only happens with the French translation. Why is this happening?

```
//This is the code for the 'Amazing Translator' app. This code was written by Nathan Hart. For maintentance tips or to add features see attached comments.

//This is the array storing all French translations from 1-30. Note: The first value "Please enter a number between 1-30" is '0'.
var frenchTranslation = ["Please enter a number between 1-30", "un","deux","trois","quatre","cinq","six","sept","huit","neuf","dix","onze","douze","treize","quatorze","quinze","seize","dix-sept","dix-huit","dix-neuf",
                         "vingt","vingt et un","vingt-deux","vingt-trois","vingt-quatre","vingt-cinq","vingt-six","vingt-sept","vingt huit","vingt-neuf","trente"];
//This is the array storing all German Translations from 1-30. Note: The first value "Please enter a number between 1-30" is '0'.
var germanTranslation = ["Please enter a number between 1-30","Eins","Zwei","Drei","Vier","Fünf","Sechs","Sieben","Acht","Neun","Zehn","Elf","Zwölf","Dreizehn","Vierzehn","Fünfzehn","Sechzehn","Siebzehn","Achtzehn","Neunzehn",
                         "Zwanzig","Einundzwanzig","Zweiundzwanzig","Dreiundzwanzig","Vierundzwanzig","Fünfundzwanzig","Sechsundzwanzig","Siebenundzwanzig","Achtundzwanzig","Neunundzwanzig","Dreiβig"];
/*This is the function used to translate the number chosen by the user into the translation
language chosen by the user. I have used 'const' instead of 'let' as 'let' is generally used for loops.
The if else statements are self explanatory, the only thing that may need changing in due time is
the values if the amount of numbers were to expand, and additional translations would be needed in the above arrays.*/
function translate()
{
const yournumber = Number(prompt("Enter your number (1-30)"));
console.log(yournumber);
const language = prompt("Choose a language - German or French");
console.log(language);

if(yournumber < 1 || yournumber > 30) {
    //This is the error allert for if a user inputs a void number.
    alert("There was an issue with your chosen number. Please enter a number between 1-30 and try again.");
}
else {
    if(language === "French") {
        //The alert for a successful French translation.
        alert("Your French translation is: "+frenchTranslation[yournumber]);
    }
    if(language === "German") {
        //The alert for a successful German translation.
        alert("Your German translation is: "+germanTranslation[yournumber]);
    }
    
        /*This is the error message for an invalid language. NOTE: This is case senistive, so users need to capatalize 'French' or 'German'.*/
    else {
        alert("Please enter a valid language(German or French). These are case sensitive.");
    } 
    
}

}
//This is the call for the translate function. Without this the function will not run, so do not delete it.
translate();
//End of code.
```

Comment: `else if (language === "German")` in your code the else branch is always executed when the language is not German

Comment: @derpirscher so to fix it I should use the else if you have added?

Comment: Yes ... Instead of `if ( language === "German")` use `else if  language === "German")`

Comment: Thank you very much @derpirscher that worked excellently.